# Difference between same kind of jQuery selections

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

What is the difference between following different ways of jQuery selections. To me they seem to be different ways of doing same thing **with same performance costs**:

```
$("#list li").hover(function () {
                $(this).addClass("red");
}, function (){
        $(this).removeClass("red");
});
```

With a greater than symbol:

```
$("#list > li").hover(function () {
                $(this).addClass("red");
}, function (){
        $(this).removeClass("red");
});
```

Add now with context:

```
$("li", $("#list")).hover(function () {
                $(this).addClass("red");
}, function (){
        $(this).removeClass("red");
});
```

Comment: This is jQuery, not CSS. And performance is almost never what it seems.

Comment: The question itself *is* about CSS, but the code to express it is indeed jQuery.

Comment: @Timotei: It's not. There is no CSS involved here, only a selector syntax that mirrors it along with some DOM querying and event binding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `#list li` finds the same set of elements, but in a modern browser it can pass the whole selector to the browser's selector engine so it might be **much** faster.
- `#list > li` finds all `li` elements that are **immediate** children of `#list`, i.e. `<ul id="list"><li>` but not `<div id="list"><ul><li>`.
- `$("li", $("#list"))` creates a jQuery object containing the element matching `#list` and then creates a new element containing any `li` elements with the context `#list`, i.e. all `li` elements that are inside `#list`. It is not really readable so don't use that.

---

There are also other ways:

- `$('#list').children('li')` equals `$('#list > li')`
- `$('#list').find('li')` equals `$('#list li')`

Both cases cannot use the speed advantages of a native `querySelectorAll` so besides being more readable they are about as bad as `$("li", $("#list"))`

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have read that use of context with IDs like `$("li", $("#list"))` make a code faster for now li will only be search in the context of #list so I suppose it should be faster than the two other way you mentioned. I agree with the readability problem you mentioned though.

Comment: Both jQuery's and a browser's native selector engine will handle a selector starting with `#id` properly, i.e. by applying the rest of the selector only on the element with the given ID.

Answer (score 1):

They are different:

`#list li` refers to any list item that is a descendant of `#list`. This is the same as `$("li", $("#list"))`

`#list > li` refers to any list element, which is a direct child (and not grandchild, and so on) of `#list`.

Answer (score 0):

`"#list li"` and `$("li", $("#list"))`: All li elements inside #list, including children, grandchildren...

`"#list > li"`: Only li childrens of #list.